# Multiple WHERE clause to SQL statement

Tags: php, sql, pdo, where-clause

I tried different approach, but still not working. The code below works, but I need to add another where clause. How to add more WHERE clauses to my SQL query?

```
public function getuserAcct(){

    $user_id =  $this->param['user_id'];
    $meter =  $this->param['meter'];
    $phone =  $this->param['phone'];

    $stmt=$this->dbConn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Monify Where user_id=".$user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $response=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($response || $response == 0)
    {
        $this->returnResponse(SUCCESS_RESPONSE,$response);
    }
    else       
    {
        $this->returnResponse(ERROR,$response);
    }
}
```

Comment: okay ..can u help add a second where clase...where a second colume is quals to $secondvariable

Comment: Your code seems to be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing prepared statements all values should be passed as placeholders and the bound in the `execute` method. Alternatively [`bindparam`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) or [`bindvalue`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) may be used, consult the manual for examples of those usages.

```
$stmt=$this->dbConn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Monify Where user_id= ?");
$stmt->execute(array($user_id));
```

To have multiple parts to a `WHERE` clause you just need to use the `OR` or `AND` operators. For example to check for a userid and phone number you could do:

```
$stmt=$this->dbConn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Monify Where user_id= ? AND phone=?");
$stmt->execute(array($user_id, $phone));
```

or if either field is optional,

```
$stmt=$this->dbConn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Monify Where user_id= ? OR phone=?");
$stmt->execute(array($user_id, $phone));
```

All this data is available in the [MYSQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html).

> The WHERE clause, if given, indicates the condition or conditions that rows must satisfy to be selected....In the WHERE expression, you can use any of the functions and operators that MySQL supports, except for aggregate (summary) functions. See [Section 9.5, “Expressions”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/expressions.html), and [Chapter 12, Functions and Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/functions.html).